# Android - spinner default margins

Tags: android

I am trying to center a spinner vertically, but it does not work since the spinner seems to have default margins that are not symmetric (the bottom margin is a bit larger than the top margin). If I set any margins to the spinner element, they are added to the default margin.

What is the recommended way to center the Spinner element vertically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that bigger bottom margin exist because of the drawable(9 patch PNG) used for the spinner(you can check the drawable in the SDK):

[image: image 1]

A solution to this is to make your own spinner's drawable(9 patch PNG) that has equal space on top and at the bottom.

Comment: Oh yes, that's it. It is really awkward that the default pngs are not symmetric.